# Minimizing a Tk Window

Tags: python, windows-7, tkinter

I have a window I made with Tkinter, I'd like to be able to minimize it. This is in Windows 7 FYI.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> w = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> w.wm_state('iconic')
```

Should work and minimize the window to the taskbar.

To minimize it to the taskbar as a button:

```
w.iconify()
```

Comment: On Mac OS X (10.9), with py27 this does not seem to minimize to the app icon on the Dock, but just make the window disappear until w.deiconify() is explicitly called.