# How to minimize Tkinter window

Tags: tkinter, window, minimize

How to minimize tkinter window and put it on taskbar, after pressing a button? I use root.overrideredirect(True) and I do not have the "close", "restore down" and "minimize" buttons anymore, so I want to create a button that replace the minimize button.

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method and `wm_iconify()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [minimizing-a-tk-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481880)

Comment: I get this error: can't iconify ".": override-redirect flag is set.

Comment: Same using `.withdraw()`?

Comment: Nope, it works like this, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimizing a Tk Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481880/minimizing-a-tk-window)

Answer (score 1):

```py
#This can be the solution to your problem.

import Tkinter
w = Tkinter.Tk()

#you can use this 
w.wm_state('iconic')

#or 

w.iconify()

#Hope this would help you...
```

Comment: Please add some explanation in your answers, not just code.

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: ok..
Let me try.